# LED Bulbs - parasitic or electric issues?

Tags: power, led

My house was built in 2005, I have no dimmer switches, voltage is about +/-4%. I’ve bought very cheap and higher quality LED bulbs. Many of them have been dying in 6 months or less, always starting by flickering (slowly).  My refrigerator is 4 years old and the LED that lights the water / ice area is flickering. I’m less well versed in power supplies and 120V design, so I have questions.

1.) Is there any way the refrigerator LED would be related to what is happening in the rest of the house? I believe the answer is no but please correct me if I’m wrong 
2.) I don’t have a scope but can get one. Is there any sort of parasitic or anything that could be going through the house causing death much too quickly?
3.) I haven’t started tracking fixtures specifically but it does seem like closet and others always die quick. Will a cheap fixture (literally screw terminal and three wires) have an effect? Everything is properly grounded

I’m going to start tracking individual fixtures and pair them with a better (Philips) / cheap (Costco Feit electric) bulb combo but in the meantime - what am I missing??

**UPDATE: See two pictures attached. Resistor burnt on top side, bottom side shows thermal issues on pads for the FET and the larger inductor and position C3. Note the MLV - doesn't seem like a surge event.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've had several cheap LED bulbs with lots of little LEDs flicker then fail. Can't say I've had many failures of bulbs with 1 or 3 big LEDs.

Comment: my impression is that they may be quality+temperature issues, what usually happens is that these lamps aren't just a led and a resistor connected to the mains, its actually a smps, and very frequently the post rectification capacitor is very tight in capacity, the quality is quite dubious and the voltage rating is also on the edge, so they lose capacity and the supply restarts

Comment: Yeah these are full bulb, it’s a power supply failure of some sort every time. Haven’t taken the time to analyze failure because my time is worth more than a $3 bulb every other month, but solving the issue would be nice.

Comment: Diego good call I’ll take a failed one and check out PS caps

Comment: In 10 years I have had exactly one LED bulb fail. Turned out to be a dry joint. I repaired it and it's still going strong. All my bulbs are Philips brand.

Comment: In the fridge specifically, it could be the compressor motor (contactor) causing spikes on the power. Only solution would be to add a snubber network.

Comment: rdtsc not worried about fixing the fridge just wondering if there is anything I’m not thinking about that would get through galvanic isolated PS and make it to the fridge’s bulbs. My assumption is they’re 100% unrelated, just want to make sure I’m correct in that assumption.

Comment: What is the largest non-resistive load on your AC mains?  Biggest pump, fan. or motor?  Also what is the biggest AC power adapter/converter?  These may generate spikes, surges, harmonics - that may not play nice with other loads.  Normally products are tested to ensure they play nice.  But if there's something that's (partially) failed or is being misused then that could zap electronic loads on the same mains..

Comment: Absolutely nothing out of the ordinary - we have two ceiling fans (both on arc fault breakers with no issues) that run probably 90% of the time on low, after that the refrigerator, water heater fan and dishwasher. AC hasn't been on in 8 months, our sump pump hasn't kicked on in 4 years (yes it still works I do test once a year). Are there any "typical" harmonics seen from cheap electrical devices that I could look for?

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything in your home, or in your neighborhood, that could be generating high voltage spikes on your power line?  Long overhead lines feeding the property can be a problem, as nearby lightning strikes can induce current into the wires.

LED lamps are often cheaply made, with components that cannot cope with even brief high voltages.

A surge protection device might help, but they aren't cheap and would need to be correctly fitted in order to work.  A device to protect the entire home needs to be fitted at the incoming supply.

Comment: My multimeter likely won’t see brief spikes but I haven’t had any neighbors having issues. Nothing specifically relating to electrical storm but could be weakening over time agreed. It’s just never a large surge causing problems - and wouldn’t the “better” LEDs at least have a MLV or TVS in it?

Comment: It would be nice if LED lamps did have surge protection, but that would add to the cost.  The most you can hope for is that the capacitors are well-specified, and not cheap ones being run at their voltage limit.

Comment: just pulled the recent failure apart and there is an MLV in there - see updates for PN as well.